# ListView doesn't update itself

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a display of some data on one fragment, and each time I click on a button it should add to the listView in the second fragment.
For some reason when I click the button I the listView doesn't change.

fragment1 :

```
nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {            
                    HistoryFragment.addToHistory( myObject );
                }});
```

HistoryFragment (listView) :

```
public class HistoryFragment extends ListFragment
{ 
    private static List<Password> historyList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        historyList = myManager.getMyObjects ();
    }

    public static void addToHistory( MyObject myObject )
    {
        historyList.add( myObject );
    }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup         container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);
    MyObjectAdapter adapter = new MyObjectAdapter( historyList );
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
    ....
    ....
    ....
private class MyObjectAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private final ArrayList<MyObject> data; 

        public MyObjectAdapter( List<MyObject> historyList ) 
        {
            data = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
            data.addAll( historyList );
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() 
        {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public MyObject getItem( int position ) 
        {            
            return data.get( position );
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO implement you own logic with ID
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final View result;

            notifyDataSetChanged();

            if (convertView == null) 
            {
                result = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.history_list_item, parent, false);
            } 
            else 
            {
                result = convertView;
            }

            MyObject item = getItem( position );

            ( (TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.historyObjectTextView) ).setText(item.toString());

            return result;
       }
    }
```

fragment main(1) :

```
  public class MainFragment extends Fragment 
 {
 Map<String,MyObject> objects  = new HashMap<String,MyObject>();
 List< MyObject > objectsList = new ArrayList< MyObject >();
 TextView nextDisplay;

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
objects = myManager.getInstance().getObjects();
objectsList = MyObject.getObjectsList();
}

@Override
 public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup                     container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) 
 {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,   false);

nextDisplay = ( TextView ) view.findViewById( R.id.displayTextView );
nextDisplay.setText( objectsList.get( 0 ).getObjectString() );

Button nextButton = ( Button ) view.findViewById( R.id.nextObjectButton );
nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {            
            if( objectsList.size() > 0 )
            {
                objects.get(objectsList.get( 0 ).getObjectString()).setTried( true );
                long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                objects.get(objectsList.get( 0 ).getObjectString()).setTime( currentTime );


                HistoryFragment.addToHistory( objectsList.get( 0 ) );
                objectsList.remove( 0 );

                if( objectsList.size() > 0  && !objectsList.get( 0 ).getTried() )
                {
                    nextCodeDisplay.setText( objectsList.get( 0 ).getObjectString() );
                }
            }           
        }});
return view;
```

}

Comment: historyList is a static List. You have to update the adapter.

Comment: I've updated the post with the onCreateView where I set the adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like This.

```
private List<Password> historyList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
private MyObjectAdapter adapter
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);
    adapter = new MyObjectAdapter( historyList );
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}

private static List<Password> historyList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    historyList = myManager.getMyObjects ();
}

public void addToHistory( MyObject myObject )
{
    historyList.add( myObject );
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: In a static method, you can't use references of the object.

Comment: That probably should just not be a static method. I just added the notifyDataSetChanged(); where it should be.

Comment: But I need to add the object from my main fragment. So I use this addToHistory method directly( hence it's static).. Otherwise I'd have to instantiate the history fragment

Comment: Im sorry but that is just bad design. You should probably not be doing that. When your fragment launches it should get the data either via api call or from the containing activity through an interface.

Comment: I know there's `setTargetFragment(...)` call but it means it's expecting a result back. Is there something similar that doesn't expect a result to communicate between two fragments?

Comment: post the fragment that starts your history fragment.

Comment: @doubleA posted it now, edited the post..
and it's not really starting it. They're both on a ViewPager activity. On fragment main if you click on a button the data passes to fragment history. In fragment history if you click remove on some item it goes back to fragment main.

Comment: I am assuming that in your R.layout.fragment_main there is a History fragment? Please post the layout file that contains your history fragment or the area where the fragments are initialized and added via fragment manager.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83265/discussion-between-bvtp-and-doublea).

Answer (score 1):

To populate or update the ListView you have to update the list used by the adapter. In your code you are updating the list inside the Fragment, not the data used by the adapter.

In your code you should do something like this:

```
adapter.add(MyObject myObject);
```

in your adapter:

```
private class MyObjectAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    public  void add( List<MyObject> historyList ) 
        {
            if (data == null)
               data = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
            data.addAll( historyList );
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


}
```

Comment: Thank you.
Im sorry though , I don't understand where should I call adapter.add (...) ?

Comment: It's actually just fine to update the data source directly and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, it's not necessary to modify the data source through the Adapter (either way works).

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the OnClickListener:

```
nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {            
                    HistoryFragment.addToHistory( myObject );
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }});
```

Comment: The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. You must call this method on your adapter

Comment: sorry, I don't understand if you mean to do that from the fragment1 or from historyFragment?